# Implementing dynamic bit-fields

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression, decoding, bit-fields

**The point is that what could happen in the following problem.**

-The elements of an array of int, are let's say 5, 5, 6, 7, 9 bits long(they are different).

How can I encode it, so that it takes 32 bits instead of the usual 160 bits?

I also want to say that on the other side (the decoding side) I don't know how big each element is. So how can I possibly decode if I receive such a data, or in other words how can I encode initially in a way that can be decoded easily?

Comment: If you also describe the context or the problem, where you would apply _this_, you can get a more helpful response.

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but this is a well-studied problem. See "universal codes" via Google.

Answer (score 2):

If the distribution of bits among those numbers is known beforehand, it's simple: Just put the bits of each element in the array to the proper position in the resulting int, like this (e.g. in C++ code):

```
unsigned int encoded = (val[0]) | (val[1] << 5) | (val[2] << 10) |
              (val[3] << 16) | (val[4] << 23);
```

...assuming that `val` is an array of int, and that it contains numbers which are 5, 5, 6, 7 and 9 bits long. Decoding is equally simple:

```
int decoded[5];
decoded[0] = encoded & 0x1F;
decoded[1] = (encoded >> 5) & 0x1F;
decoded[2] = (encoded >> 10) & 0x3F;
decoded[3] = (encoded >> 16) & 0x7F;
decoded[4] = (encoded >> 23);
```

If the bit lengths aren't known beforehand, and the only known fact is, that their bit size combined is 32, then, *for the general case, it's impossible* to encode them into a maximum of 32 bits; because you already need this amount of bits to store the actual numbers; but you would also have to know the bit lengths of the encoded numbers; for this you would need additional storage. This all is valid provided that these numbers aren't somehow redundant and could be compressed.

There are of course ways to make it shorter than 4 bytes per integer; depending on the exact properties of the numbers to work on, one or the other algorithm might be better suited; here is a short list of a few possible algorithms:

- If you know that the integers can be a maximum of 9 bits long, you could use the simple method shown above, but with offsets of 9 to store the numbers; you would get down to 45 bits for 5 values with this method.
- Having a length indicator before each element is another possibility (as suggested by [Robert Rouhani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677169/671366))
- Another is e.g. proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354229/variable-length-integer-encoding) (using [Dlugosz' Variable-Length-Integer](http://www.dlugosz.com/ZIP2/VLI.html))
- You could also use [Variable-length quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity).

The first two methods have the disadvantage that they only can represent a fixed maximum number of bits. This kind of processing falls into the domain of *compression*, for a more theoretical analysis make sure to read up on some literature on that topic; of special interest here are [Universal Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_%28data_compression%29), as pointed out in Kaganar's comment; the last two algorithms in the list above are such universal codes. They should get you down to 48 bits for your example input of 5 values with 5,5,6,7 and 9 bits (4 times 8 bits for the 4 values having less than 8 bits, and 1 time 16 bits for the 9 bits number). The advantage of these two methods to the other methods on the list is that they are suited for *arbitrarily large* numbers; there might be other Universl Codes better suited to your purpose, make sure to check out the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could include 4-6 bits prior to each element that contains the size in bits of the element, depending on the maximum size of an element (4 if max size < 16, 5 if max size < 32, 6 if max size < 64).

Decoding would be as simple as:

- read 4 bits to determine element size
- read x bits as the element (where x is element size)

Because of the variable size, you won't be able to pack the data to 32 bytes as you need to include some sort of size indicator for each element. In this case, assuming you're using 4 bits for size, you'll be using 52 bits, which is only 32.5% of the original size of 160 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I think compacting 5, 5, 6, 7, 9 into 32 bit is impossible. Too small storage to fit all the information.

First of all, we can minimize padding bits by observing maximum possible bits of a element. If we use 32 bits variable for maximum 10 bits elements we are wasting 22 bits. We can get rid of  22 bits per each element with 10 bit data type.

Other than this need some inflate, deflate scheme, and I think it not fit well to small data or number array like OP's example.